# refuse non ssl/tls connection?

Tags: tls, apache-2.2

i have a webserver and I have enabled the apache2 ssl/tls.
so I can access my website with "https://IPADDR".

but i can also access with just "http://IPADDR".

is it possible to block non-ssl/tls using html connection requests from the server side? (something like more configuration with apache2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you want to *refuse* connections, and not just redirect?

You can implement a more user friendly experience by having your http:// connections redirect to https://

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.yoursite.com
    ServerAlias yoursite.com

    Redirect permanent / https://www.yoursite.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If someone goes to `http://IPADDR/foo/bar?whatever` they will be seamlessly redirected to `https://IPADDR/foo/bar?whatever`.